# Return string from simple regex in php

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract a string from another string with a regex. This is my regex:

```
/^httpamp$/
```

I looked at the php functions like  `preg_filter ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject)`, but I don't get how it works. I know pattern is this: `/^httpamp$/`, and `$subject` is my initial string, but what is replacement for??

Comment: You probably want [`preg_match()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) rather than `preg_filter() / preg_replace()` if you are just looking to match a substring.

Comment: Please write an example. For example, if you have `adsfasdfadfshttpampasdfasdfsdf`, need you extract what from this? nothing? (^ and $ blocking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$replacement` element refers to what you want to replace the pattern with - either as an array or string, but you don't need to use `preg_filter()` to identify substrings.

If you're looking to identify part of a string (regardless of length) then use `preg_match()`:

```
<?php
  // The string to seach
  $yourString = "the lazy fox";

  // The pattern to match
  $pattern = '/^the/';

  // The function to use
  preg_match($pattern, $yourString, $matches);

  // Output the $matches produced (formatted)
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($matches);
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

There are a few additional options (flags/offset) which you can use and which you can find out more about [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)